# modifying 4 variable in one click in vue

Tags: vue.js, components

I have 4 buttons that need  to load a component. Every time a component is loaded, the last one has to go away.

I have this code:

```js
const showFoo = ref(false)
const showMyBar = ref(False)
const showMyBaz = ref(false)
const showMyPan = ref(false)
```

```html
<button @click="showFoo">add a new find</button>
<button @click="showBar">my table</button>
<button @click="showBaz">my wall of fame</button>
<button @click="showPan">my blog</button>

setup(){
<div v-if="showFoo"> < FooComponent /> </div>
<div v-if="showBar"> < BarComponent /> </div>
<div v-if="showBaz"> < BazComponent /> </div>
<div v-if="showPan"> < PanComponent /> </div>
}
```

I use the composition API...
How can I make one component disapear and the new one appear? Is ther an easy way to do this? I'm learning vue3 at the moment!

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Load the Components First

```
<div>
    <div>
       <button @click="showFoo">add a new find</button>
       <button @click="showBar">my table</button>
       <button @click="showBaz">my wall of fame</button>
       <button @click="showPan">my blog</button>
    </div>
    <div v-if="showFoo"> < FooComponent /> </div>
    <div v-else-if="showBar"> < BarComponent /> </div>
    <div v-else-if="showBaz"> < BazComponent /> </div>
    <div v-else-if="showPan"> < PanComponent /> </div>
</div>
```

Create a data and set first one to true

```
data {
  return {
    showFoo: true,
    showBar: false,
    showBaz: false,
    showPan: false,
  }
}
```

In the Methods

```
hideFoo() {
   this.showFoo = false
   this.showBar = true
}

hideBar() {
   this.showBar = false
   this.showBaz = true
}

hideBaz() {
   this.showBaz = false
   this.showPan = true
}

hidePan() {
   this.showPan = false
   this.showFoo = true
}
```

Comment: `showFoo() {
   this.showFoo = false` that looks bit strange, shouldn't it set it to `true` or be called something else?

Comment: @TJ at the data we ady declared `showFoo` as true. So the first  component `showFoo` will show

Comment: Shouldn't this be  called `hideFoo() { this.showFoo = false; ... }` then?

Comment: @TJ ahh Yes my bad XD Hahahaha. I was doing something and I saw this one. am going to edit it now XD

Comment: I just realiser that the code editor here replaced my v-ifs by v_else-ifs... it kinda gave me the answer.... :-)

Comment: @Posoroko can you verify this answer?